# Thread stopping issue android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, splash-screen

I want to stop a running thread while click on the splash screen, if I don't click on screen, after the thread execution, it will launch another Activity. But getting `UnSupportedException`, how do I solve it?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    iImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iIcon);
    splashImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_image);

    iImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    splashImage.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    splashTimer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginAuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    splashTimer.start();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(splashTimer.isAlive())
        splashTimer.stop();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.iIcon:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutUsActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.splash_image:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginAuthenticationActivity.class));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    finish();
}
```

Log:

```
01-27 03:27:01.189: W/dalvikvm(1080): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1076)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1063)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at com.app.wooqer.SplashActivity.onClick(SplashActivity.java:48)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-27 03:27:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(1080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the StackTrace?

Comment: You should use `interrupt()` instead of `stop()`. `stop()` is unsafe.

Comment: What they said.  Also, there's better ways to do a splash screen.  Using a thread and an activity is a waste.  Pop up a full screen dialog and send a message to a handler with a 5000 ms delay.  When the handler runs close the dialog.  No need for extra threads and second activities.

Comment: @A--C : i tried interrupt(), but its not stopping, login screen is launching 2 times.

Comment: That makes sense actually.

Comment: @umesh it actually is stopping (well it's interrupted), but your startActivity is then called after the catch block. Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is very wasteful (any splash screen is wasteful, but using Threads like this is more so), but to fix your issue:

use `interrrupt();` intead of `stop();`

As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) say for `stop()`

```
Throws UnsupportedOperationException.
```

And to fix the duplicate issue, move the `startActivity()` inside the `try` so it looks like this:

```
public void run() {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginAuthenticationActivity.class));
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finish();
}
```

That way when you call `interrupt()` all your Activity does is `finish()` and the duplicate `startActivity()` is not called.

To further explain:

Very first issue: `stop()` throws an exception by default, since it's an unsafe method which you're not supposed to use.

Then when you used `interrupt()`, you had `startActivity()` in the run method **after** the catch block. When you interrupted, `startActivity()` was called once in `run()` and once in `onClick()`. By moving `startActivity()` inside the `try` block to right after `Thread.sleep()`, when `interrupt()` interrupts the `Thread`, the rest of the `try` block isn't executed. This means that you now only have one `startActivity()` call instead of two. For more information, read up on [exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: its working perfectly, can you please tell me what was the problem before, i still didn't understand.