# Android:How to finish/stop the thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

The app will breakdown when t.stop();
situation: I want to save the textview text to array every 2s(25times);

```
t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // update TextView here!
                        if (i < 25) {
                            mypDialog.setProgress(i * 4);
                            getRssi(iBeaconPosition, i);
                            i++;
                        } else {
                            finishCalibration();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
};
t.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
t.interrupt();
```

For more information read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541907/thread-stopping-issue-android) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756862/how-to-stop-a-thread);

Comment: If you finally used this solution, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You This is I want to do